# How to code registration in MS Access VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am cluesless for coding in my registration page written in aspx.vb.
The page allows the student to register and the information will be kept in the MS Access database. The clear button is to clear all the textboxes and droplists

Username textbox
student id textbox
course (dropdownlist) needs to be connected to dtb.

Submit and clear button

Code written so far:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class WebForm5
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL-PC\Desktop\OnlineDB.mdb")
End Sub
Protected Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()


End Sub
End Class
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you need to look into .ExecuteNonQuery and .ExecuteReader objects of the Class OleDB.

It's here you can execute SQL queries to your access database.

an example:

```
   Public Sub ACNonquery(ByVal utos As String)
       Dim Accessconn as new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL-PC\Desktop\OnlineDB.mdb")
       Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand(utos, accessconn)
       Try
          accessconn.Open()
          sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
          accessconn.Close()
       Catch ex As Exception
          accessconn.Close()
          MsgBox(utos & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)
       End Try
    End Sub
```

call it like this:

```
    ACNonquery("insert into tablename values('data1','data2');")
```

In this example, I used the NonQuery to execute an SQL command (in this case, an insert) to my access database.